# replacing a transformer with one of slightly more voltage

Tags: transformer

[image]I have some audio subwoofer amplifiers that require a 96v center tap 5 amp transformer for a non-regulated supply (Cerwin Vega Sub 150). I can source 90vct 4.4 amp $57 and 100vct 5 amp $51 transformers, a difference from 400VA to 500VA. Of course I want mass quantities of power, so is 100vct too risky? I see that I need to look at the transistors and try to identify them and get the specs.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the full schematic. I would just go for the 90 V transformer. The increase in power by using 100 V (assuming the amplifiers can handle that) is negligible, given two identical amps. One with the 90 V, other 100 V, it would surprise me if anyone could hear the difference. Measure it yes but hear it, no.

Comment: this bend has a 35mph speed limit, should I take it at 30 or 40? What bend, what subwoofer amplifier? Most people get away with taking bends too fast, maybe your amplifier transistors will tolerate 100v, maybe the heatsinking is sufficient. Who knows?
 Certainly nobody could answer with the limited information you give. The difference between 90 and 100 is only 1dB, that is, inaudible. Is it worth the risk?

Comment: If you actually need 5A, then the 90V one is under-powered and could overheat.  The difference between 96V and 100V is only 4%, less than the tolerance in a domestic mains supply.

Comment: @SimonB Please post that as an answer.

Comment: You can get custom-wound transformers. They might not be too expensive, or even any more expensive than the ones you listed.

Comment: Having designed audio amplifiers for a living and reverse engineered others, far from all amplifiers have 11 % margin to spare on rail voltage so I would definitely not go from 90 V to 100 V without deep knowledge of the entire circuit. Also, "90vct" is a strange way of saying "90 V, center tapped" and prone to confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually need 5A, then the 90V one is under-powered and could overheat.

The difference between 96V and 100V is only 4%.  This is less than the tolerance in a domestic mains supply (possibly ±6% or ±10%, depending on where you live).

You're unlikely to notice any increase in volume.  If your mains supply is close to the top of its tolerance, then in the long term you could be stressing the components of the amplifier.

Comment: It seems that the closest I can come is 80v 5A center tapped $51. The transformer has 15v taps for other circuits. I know that I will lose some power, but may gain some safety if I use a 4 Ohm speaker. (I always monitor the temperature when first loading an amp.) Thanks for the help. – Richard Anderson yesterday